# Eclipse does not set ups for Android development. (No tools(sdk manager,avd manager) , no adt installed.)

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin

What i have:

I downloaded eclipse adt with android SDK from google developers.And jdk 8u5 from off                                                                site.

1. When i open eclipse: the simple juno loads .
2. Inside: no tools,no managers.
3. Loading adt, which should ne in already:Help->Install New Software->(using  https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse/)
4. Nothing changes. No adt,no tools, no managers. But it is installed somewhere...
5. SDK is linked in Window->Preferences.(No managers, but below i can see list of SDK targets and some 4.4 there.)

What i want:

1. I want my eclipse be with adt plugin. With sdk manager,avd manager.
2. I want to create Android project normaly.
3. I want to download sdks.

P.S.
1st time i have such problems and i can't believe in this. I even used 2 different manuals about setting up Eclipse ADT with Android SDK. During this day I reinstalled IDE like 24 times. 
Windows 7 64bit.
Installing adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to go back to the ADT bundle before this one there are problems right now, here is a place you can download from :

https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.zip - Windows 7 64 bit https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321.zip - Windows 7 32 bit
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321.zip - Mac 64 bit

I had the same problem like you, its a problem in the new ADT .. install this one until google will fix it in a new version.

Comment: I installed this version Win7-64. But have the same problems .What could it  be ?

Comment: @Animus Ok, delete your Eclipse, SDK and JDK .. then extract my download, install JDK again and run Eclipse.

Comment: @ user3784668
I did that already . 
Never had such problems .